# getting playframework to serve a generated file in resource_managed

Tags: playframework-2.0

I use sbt-js

https://github.com/untyped/sbt-plugins/tree/develop/sbt-js

to generate a compressed concatenation of all my javascript files

the compressed file generated by sbt-js ends up in the *resource_managed* directory

(target/scala2.10/resource_managed/main/all.js)

Now I need to get Play to serve this file, it seems that I need to create a 
route for it, but can't figure out which one, I've tried variations of this :

```
GET /assets/all.js  controllers.Assets.at(path="/resource_managed/main", file="all.js")
```

with no success.

Answer (score 0):

The (known) contents of resource_managed/main is put in the root of the classpath so if what you are doing would work it would be Assets.at(path="/", file="all.js")

The bad news is that resource_managed is reserved for files generated by the play asset compilers, those actually return every file outputted so that play/sbt knows about the file. So to get that to work you would need to make the sbt-js-compilation an asset compiler and include that among the play asset compilers.

The good news is that there is a concept of unmanaged resources which can be anything you feel like. To use that you would set the key `unmanagedResourceDirectories` in your SBT configuration, for example something like this:

```
val myCompiledJsDir = SettingsKey[File]("js-output-dir", "Where my js is compiled to")

val myJsSettings = Seq(
    myCompiledJsDir <= target(_ / "my-js-output"),
    (unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile) <+= myCompiledJsDir
)
```

and then append myJsSettings to your play project

```
val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, Dependencies.all).settings(
   ...
).settings(myJsSettings: _*)
```

This should make play pick up your compiled js just fine, the directory you add will be added to the classpath root and will be packed into the play dist zip-file etc.